# JavaScript: Inline Script with SRC Attribute?

Tags: javascript, include

I'm used to including and using JS like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/path/to/script.js'></script>
....
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Do some stuff here, using resources defined in script.js.');
</script>
```

Just out of curiosity, does anyone know the rule for having an inline script with a src attrib, like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/path/to/script.js'>
    alert('Do some stuff here, using resources defined in script.js.');
</script>
```

I can test what DOES happen in various browsers, but would like to know what the official behavior is.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's either one or the other, not both. The `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag has precedence over the body of the tag.

[HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1):

> The script may be defined within the
>   contents of the SCRIPT element or in
>   an external file. If the `src` attribute
>   is not set, user agents must interpret
>   the contents of the element as the
>   script. If the `src` has a URI value,
>   user agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via
>   the URI.

Comment: Didn't realize I was racing. :-)

Comment: Here's a link to the newer [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts) (see the text above the code example)

Answer (score 5):

The HTML specification states

> If the src has a URI value, user
>   agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via
>   the URI.

Answer (score 3):

From the [HTML 4 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1):

> If the src attribute is not set, user
>   agents must interpret the contents of
>   the element as the script. If the src
>   has a URI value, user agents must
>   ignore the element's contents and
>   retrieve the script via the URI.