# Load jQuery into Django

Tags: jquery, django

I have a really basic question.  I'm trying to build some AJAX functionality into a Django project.  I plan to use jQuery.  Right now, I'm just running the code locally through Linux. I've been testing some code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide) so I'm reasonably certain that it works.  But I'm having trouble figuring where to put the jQuery source code in combination with my settings.

I downloaded [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js) and put it in what I think is my Media folder.  My settings.py file reads as follows:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'books/media/')<br>
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/books/media/'
```

In my html template, I'm referencing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
```

But none of my functions are working.  I'm sure it's something stupid and obvious (though clearly not obvious to me).  How do I correctly source jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hardcode the link as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/books/media/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
```

or if you render your template with a `RequestContext` and use the `django.core.context_processors.media` context processor, then you can access `MEDIA_URL` in your template.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}}js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
```

Comment: awesome!  Any idea why this works: <script type="text/javascript" src="/books/media/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> . . .code. . .</script>  but this doesn't: <script type="text/javascript" src="/books/media/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"> . . .code. . .</script>

Comment: You can't have src and code in the script tag at the same time. It's just the way html is specified. See this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll need `src="/books/media/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"`

Also, though, I do it thusly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.4");
</script>
```

Comment: Is it preferable to load it like this or to download it to my own directory?

Comment: I prefer doing it this way because there's 1 less Javascript file to worry about and I use google.load for a few other things as well such as their maps API. Really though, there's nothing wrong with downloading it into your own directory if you prefer.

Comment: In theory it can make your website faster. If a user goes to website A that uses Google to host jQuery, then visits your website, then jQuery is already in the browser cache, so doesn't need to be downloaded again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup Django to serve your media files (otherwise, serve them from a proper HTTP server). Add the following line to your `url.py`:

```
(r'^mymedia/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Make sure you change the `mymedia` part to align with your media directory.

Comment: what does it mean: to serve static media?  And is this only necessary from a local project?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

1. Access the URL `http://localhost:8000/books/media/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` using your browser or `curl` and see what turns up.
2. Check your URL configuration to see that you have an URL defined for serving media using static serve.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** put your jquery-2.0.3.js in the APP's "static" subfolder,like "books/static/jquery-2.0.3.js";

**Step2:** config your urls.py, add the following line:

```
r('^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve'),
```

**Step3:** in your template file, use the js file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

That is all.