# Django - Trouble Loading JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I cannot load JQuery no matter what I do! I did exactly what was suggested in this Question --> [Load jQuery into Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679674/load-jquery-into-django) but I dont want to use dynamic directories in my settings.py. Static directories are fine as this is just a personal project.

From Settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/usr/local/djcode/mysite/media/'

MEDIA_URL = 'http://<my ip address>/django/media/'
```

From my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mysite/media/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```

When I go to this html file, it loads, but none of my JQuery functions work.

ADDITIONAL INFO: My website (urls.py, app folders, and media folder) are all in /usr/local/djcode/mysite/. 
The root url of my django website is http:///django/

Please Help!!!

Comment: And the problem is? What's the output? what did you try? I'm asking because what you are showing here is not what the answer in your link says you have to do.

Comment: I can load my html page fine, but none of my JQuery functions work.

Comment: Are you using the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` var? what's the output in the browser for the script tag?

Answer (score 1):

If your media url is "http://127.0.0.1/django/media" then the path of the file would be "http://127.0.0.1/django/media/jquery-1.2.6.js"  Try just using your media url in the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```

Comment: That seemed to fix things, although I'm not sure I understand why. Why can't I use src="/mysite/media/jquer...."

Comment: Why should you be able to? That has nothing to do with the value you've defined for MEDIA_URL.

Comment: you can't use "/mysite/media/..." because you haven't configured anything to serve that url path.

Comment: django_dev_101: did this answer your question?