# JavaScript/HTML div creation error

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make a basic sensor pad for HTML (JavaScript), which creates 500 small `div`s which then turn red on mouse hover. However, when I tried it, nothing was created

example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SensorPad Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="SensorPad.js">
window.onload = createSensor;
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
.sPad{
    width: 0.4px;
    height: 0.4px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 0.1px solid #000;
}
.uPad{
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

SensorPad.js

```
var sPos;
var count = 1;
function createSensor(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 500; ++i){
        var pad = document.createElement('div');
        pad.className = 'sPad';
        pad.id = 'pad' + count.toString();
        pad.onmousehover = function(){sPos = parseInt(pad.id); clearPads(); pad.className = 'uPad';};
        count++;
    }
}
function clearPads(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= count; ++i){
        var n = 'pad' + i.toString();
        var p = document.getElementById(n);
        p.className = 'sPad';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem cries out for a fiddle. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sQdz6/

Comment: Side note, your HTML in invalid and there's no real point in specifying fractional pixel values since the browser will just round it.

Comment: You cannot run inline code inside the <script> tag if it contains a src attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use separate `script` tags - one for the external reference and another for the onload.

As for the divs, you're creating them but you're not adding them to the DOM.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 500; ++i){
    var pad = document.createElement('div');
    pad.className = 'sPad';
    pad.id = 'pad' + count.toString();
    pad.onmousehover = function(){sPos = parseInt(pad.id); clearPads(); pad.className = 'uPad';};
    document.body.appendChild(pad)
    count++;
}
```

EDIT: Addressing Teemu's concern you might simply want to use CSS for that hover instead so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 500; ++i){
    var pad = document.createElement('div');
    pad.className = 'sPad';
    pad.id = 'pad' + i.toString();
    document.body.appendChild(pad)
}
```

css

```
.sPad{
    width: 0.4px;
    height: 0.4px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 0.1px solid #000;
}
.sPad:hover{
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: "`pad.onmousehover`", seriously?

Comment: The hover wasn't the OP's question and is a part of his code. Separate issue.

Comment: A _good_ answer should provide a **working** solution, nevertheless what is the OP's code, IMHO. Though Eric's answer is needed for even to execute the code. Anyway, +1 after update.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing

```
document.body.appendChild(pad);
```

Answer (score 3):

First the code will not run because of the way you added the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SensorPad.js">
window.onload = createSensor;
</script>
```

you can not have code inside and a src

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SensorPad.js"></src>    
<script type="text/javascript"
    window.onload = createSensor;
</script>
```