# Passing variable from jade file to javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a node express app. I am trying to pass a value from jade to a javascript file.

On the server side I am using:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Title', test: 1 });
```

In my index.jade file I have the following:

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='./javascripts/ui.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='./javascripts/handle.js').
  var data = !{test}
block content
  h3= title
```

In my handle.js file I have

```
$(function() {

    console.log(data);
});
```

On the console I get a message saying data is not defined. How do I pass the value of test from the jade file to the javascript file? Currently `test` is just an interger, but eventually it will be an object which contains a lot of properties.

How do I properly pass the value from the jade file to the javascript file?

Comment: You'll have to use a separate `script.` for inline scripts. [Inline Script with SRC Attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute)

Comment: That response seems to say that I cannot have an inline source and use the src argument at the same time. So, how am I supposed to pass the value from the jade file to the js file?

Comment: How do I make it such that the variables defined in the inline script are associated with the javascript src file(in this example, it is handle.js)

Answer (score 0):

That will only work for literals. For objects you can do this:

```
var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};
```

As for the showing undefined part, check if its getting properly set and it is the correct variable.

Make sure you are loading in correct order:

```
script(type='text/javascript')                                                   
  var data =!{JSON.stringify(test)};
script(src='./javascripts/handle.js)
```

Comment: I tried this, and I still get an error saying data is an unreferenced type.

Comment: I'm still getting an unreferenced error with the new answer

Comment: @AndroidDev93 Are you sure it is getting passed, try printing on the html and post the result in question.

Comment: I am printing out the values in HTML. When I do JSON.stringify(test) through HTML and then iterate through the properties I am able to print out the various properties. But when I try to do the same through javascript, it isn't working. Printing data returns undefined.