# How to change javascript datatype value in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a rt.js file in which `var k=1;` is written. And i have linked it to my html file ss.html. I want to change k value to 2 and then want to print it.

The code is:

```
<html>
 <body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rt.js">
 k=2;
document.write(k);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**problem**: Now the problem is that its supposed to print 2 but its printing 1 only. can you tell me what should i need to do?

Comment: A `<script>` will not execute both a `src` and inline content. Each needs its own element.

Comment: "[Inline Script with SRC Attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to seperate your `<script>` tags, like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rt.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
k=2;
document.write(k);
</script>
```