# Javascript: Storing Data in Variables. Beginner error?

Tags: javascript

Too begin with this is not my code. I'm a beginner hobby coder with Javascript and am using a book from which this exercise came from to learn from. Unfortunately the publishers website is missing the files for the book hence my issue.

The code below should when run show the contents of the str variable. When I run it though I just get a blank browser screen. I've checked for any obvious glaring typos but can't see any. To begin with I created a html document as below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Variable</title>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "variable.js">
obj.innerHTML = str + ":" + typeof str;
</script>   

<body>
<div id = "panel"> </div>
</body>
```

Then I typed the output code in Notepad and saved that in the same folder as the html code. I also saved the code as a Javascript file in the same place

The output code is below

```
 function init()
{
    //STATEMENTS TO BE EXECUTED GO HERE
var str = "Text Content in Javascript";

obj.innerHTML = str + ":" + typeof str;
}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

From my limited knowledge of Javascript I'm guessing that the code to output the result isn't being seen but I don't understand why or more likely I'm missing something blindingly obvious. Where is the missing link?

Comment: You can’t combine JS code and a source for a JS file _in the same `<script>` tag_. A related question is [JavaScript: Inline Script with SRC Attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056325/4642212). So this question is a duplicate of all those questions in the “Linked” section of that related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on  here.

- Missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Missing `</head>` closing tag
- Missing `</html>` closing tag
- Code duplication in the script tag calling `variable.js` and your variable.js file.
- Missing `obj` variable assignment in variable.js

Here is working code to study:

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Variable</title>
    <script src="variable.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="panel"></div>

     <script>document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false);</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**variable.js file**

```
function init() {
    //STATEMENTS TO BE EXECUTED GO HERE
  var str = "Text Content in Javascript";

  var obj = document.getElementById("panel");
  obj.innerHTML = str + ":" + typeof str;
}
```

Happy learning!

Comment: Many thanks for that. I've taken a print out so I can study it in my own time. I want to understand the logic behind it as thats the best way to learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You'r missing a script tag.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "variable.js"></script>
<script>
obj.innerHTML = str + ":" + typeof str;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Only way I'll get better at coding is to learn from my mistakes even if they are with hindsight obvious ones.