# XMLHttpRequest with php will not work

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to get this solved for 2 weeks now and still have no success.

#### JavaScript:

```js
var quotenum = 0;
var xmlhttp = null;
var rt = "";

function ChangeQuote() {
    quotenum++;
    xmlhttp = null;
    //alert("quotenum= "+quotenum);
    if (quotenum === 0) {
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            rt = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //alert("quote= "+rt);
            alert("request number= " + xmlhttp.length);
            document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = rt;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("Get", "getquote.php?q=" + quotenum, false);
    //xmlhttp.open("GET", "getquote.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug&q=" + quotenum, false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    //var thediv = document.getElementById("quote");   
    return false;
}
```

#### PHP:

```php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$q="";
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","sequence","babylon");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query="SELECT quotetext FROM quote where quotenum='".$q."'";
$show=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die ("Error");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($show)){
    echo $row["quotetext"];
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?
Using WAMP I can see the correct result when I run the PHP file in a browser.
I also try to use Jquery instead.

```js
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script>
                var quotenum = 0;
                // var xmlhttp = null;
                // var rt = "";
                function ChangeQuote() {
                    quotenum++;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "getquote.php?q="+quotenum,
                        method: "get",
                        data: {
                            q: quotenum
                        }
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = data.quotetext;
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Not certain that DONE is a valid property.

`if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status === 200)`

I'd try xmlHttp.readyState === 4

`if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)`

Comment: The alert in the block appears... alert("request number= "+xmlhttp.length); Although the value is undefined. I did try xmlHttp.readyState === 4 but it made no difference

Comment: `xmlhttp.length` *would* be undefined; there's no such property. Did you mean `xmlhttp.responseText.length` (or its alias here, `rt.length`)?

Comment: any errors/warnings in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. This was showing in the Javascript console.

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery? Ajax requests are simple and fast with it + you have less code to write. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: OK I'm using JQuery now but all it does is return to last visited page and does not update the innerHTML of the document element which was my aim.

Comment: [obligatory] you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You might be liable.

Comment: You should not have inline js with a `script` tag that has a `src` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: How are you calling `ChangeQuote`? Sounds like you're submitting a form and canceling the Ajax request.

Comment: I call it by clicking the following                                                                                                            <form>
                    <input type="submit" value="Change Quote" onclick="return ChangeQuote();" >    
                </form>
How am I cancelling the ajax request?

Comment: It looks like what I'm trying to do is not possible. My web page is created in Netbeans using Java Server faces framework and Glassfish server.In order for my ajax code to work I would need a PHP servere as well.

Comment: So far I have not found a way to include a PHP server in the NetBeans Project. If anyone has any suggestions I would be grateful. Thanks to all who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The only noticable error I see is you inlining your js with the `script` tag that has a `src` attribute.

[HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1):

> The script may be defined within the
>   contents of the SCRIPT element or in
>   an external file. If the `src` attribute
>   is not set, user agents must interpret
>   the contents of the element as the
>   script. If the `src` has a URI value,
>   user agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via
>   the URI.

Comment: OK I fixed that, but still no joy