# How do you automatically run an external JavaScript function with a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run an external javascript function when the page loads and the function takes a variable that I can only pass through the page which where the javascript function is called from.

HTML Page

```
<head>
<script src="path/to/file.js" type="text/javscript>
window.onload = function() {
doFunction(variable);
}
</script>
</head>
```

Javascript file

```
function doFunction(variable){
//do the stuff here
}
```

Comment: Each `<script>` element can either have a `src` or inline code, not both in one. Move the inline code to a 2nd `<script>` element. – [Inline Script with SRC Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Would I just do a window.onload(doFunction(variable));? If I am using src

Comment: @JonathanLonowski how so?

Comment: Add a 2nd `<script>` element after the current `</script>`. Move the inline JavaScript into it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
<script src="path/to/file.js" type="text/javscript></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
      doFunction(variable);
});
</script>
</head>
```

The reference script tag(for including external files) should not include any external javascript code in it. you can only reference a external file.

To add any other javascript that should be between seperate script tags

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't loading the `file.js` asynchronously, you can include the script in the header. As long as you call the function AFTER the script is loaded, it should work fine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="path/to/file.js" type="text/javscript>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        doFunction('someVal');
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```