# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: javascript

> code3.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined at espaces_debut (code3.js:8) at onload (Ex4.htm:11)

**In Ex4.htm :**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Ex4</title>
<script language="javascript" src="code3.js">
ch=prompt ("ch ") ; 
alert (espaces_debut(ch));
</script>
</head>
<body onload="espaces_debut()">
</body>
</html>
```

**IN code3.js :**

```
function espaces_debut(ch)
{
i=-1;
do 
{
i=i+1
}   
while (ch.charAt(i)=' ')  ;
return ( ch.substr(0,i-1) ) ;   
}
```

I get this Error , help pls

Comment: Note: [Inline Script with SRC Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056325/javascript-inline-script-with-src-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to call function `escapes_debut` on `onload` without parameter. `ch` is undefined and has no `charAt` method.

Remove `onload` attribute from `body`.

**EDIT:** due to comment below:
You don't need this function, where are more errors. Use just `.trim()` function.

```
ch.prompt('ch');
alert(ch.trim());
```

Note that prompt has two optional parameters. The first one isn't value, but label. Value is the second one, if is set.

Comment: I did that before , i don't get an error but the page is not asking me to write (ch ) while i'm writing       ch=prompt ("ch ") ;    , sorry , i'm just a beginner x)

Comment: @SaiefZaneti: what's your goal? What should your code has to do?

Comment: My Code is supposed to read a string (in the html file )  , delete the spaces at the beginning and return it (in the function in the js file ) . then show the result in the html file .I can add the function to the main html file and it will work fine , but i'm supposed to do them in separate files .

Comment: @SaiefZaneti: see my edited answer... you don't need your function.